# Set function default this value

Tags: javascript, scope, sandbox

**Background:**

I am running a sandboxed iframe which only has the permission "allow-scripts". In the sandbox a script is loaded with custom js provided by the user. Now i want to manage access to global functions/objects like XMLHttpRequest. Currently i achieve that with the following code:

```
const CLEARED_WINDOW_SCOPE= {};
const scope = { /* Here goes the globals the script should have access too */};
const propertyNames = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(window);

for(let property of propertyNames){
    CLEARED_WINDOW_SCOPE[property] = undefined;
}

with(CLEARED_WINDOW_SCOPE){
    with(scope){
        (function (window, self, frames, globalThis){
            ${scriptContent}
        }).call(scope, scope, scope, scope, scope); 
    }
}
```

The script does the following:

1. Create object with all window property names set to undefined
2. Create object with all properties the user should have access too
3. Wrap the user code with two `with` statements the first clears all globals the second grands access to the defined ones
4. Wrap the user code with a function that is called with the `scope` as `this` value

So far everything works perfectly as excepted.

**Problem:**

The main problem that i have right now is that when a user defines a function like that:

```
function aFunction(){
   console.log(this);
}
```

He gains access to the normal window object because the default `this` value within a function is the window.

**Question:**

Is it somehow possible to change the default `this` value of a function to the `this` value of the surrounding scope. Since the user creates the script i can't wrap all function calls with `aFunction.bind(scope)`. Or is there any other value to prevent the access to the global window object?

Comment: I guess the only way to really separate the execution contexts would be something like [js.js](https://github.com/jterrace/js.js/). Otherwise there are probably always ways to find a way to escape the sandbox at least far enough to get to things like XMLHttpRequest...

Comment: @CherryDT js.js looks interesting. Thank you for that. I will look into it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it somehow possible to change the default this value of a function to the this value of the surrounding scope.

No, but you can do the next best(?) thing: setting it to `undefined`. Just force strict mode:

```js
"use strict";

// User's code
(function (){
  console.log(this)
})();
```

Also, I'm not a JavaScript security expert, but JS sandboxing is a really complex topic because of things like prototype pollution.

**Edit:** As [CherryDT](https://stackoverflow.com/u/1871033/) noted in the comments, this method is not completely secure. Users can still access the `<iframe>` `window` by creating a function with the `Function` constructor, for example. Also, a reference to the main `window` can be obtained through the `<iframe>` `window` ([`window.parent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/parent)).

It's maybe OK to use this solution for *user-supplied* code (since users can just open the DevTools console and start typing), but make sure the code comes from *the user* and never from a URL search parameter, for example. If the code is completely distrusted, I would recommend to use a well-known library like [Google Caja](https://github.com/google/caja).

Comment: I never though about strict mode. That is actually a really good idea. Thanks. If i run into any issues i will have a look at google's caja.

Comment: Note that indirect eval, such as `(0, eval)('this')` can still be used to gain access to the global object, or also `Function('return this')()` which will escape strict mode.

Comment: Another way without evaluating anything would be set a property on `Object.prototype`, and since the global object also is an `Object`, we can access is global variable. Then all we have to do is make the getter return `this`: `Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, 'pwn3d', { get () { return this }}); console.log(pwn3d) // logs window object`